# how to access realm result and iterate through the results

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to get the realm object results and iterate through the results like an array. Here is my code

```
 func getStore(){
    
    let user = realmApp.currentUser()
    let partitionValue = "depth"

    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: (user?.configuration(partitionValue: partitionValue))!,

        callback: { (maybeRealm, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                fatalError("Failed to open realm: \(error!)")
            }
            guard let realm = maybeRealm else {
                fatalError("realm is nil!")
            }
            // realm opened
            let tasks = realm.objects(shipwreck.self)
        

            
            print("Here is the result", tasks)

        })
}
```

however this is what i got as print out

> > Sync: Connection[1]: Connected to endpoint 'xxxxxxxxx' (from '1xxxxxxx0')
> > Here is the result []

how can I access the realm result and iterate through them?

Comment: There are a number of issues with the code. `shipwreck.self` is your Object in realm but what is `SomeObject.self` as it's a different object? Generally, don't cast a Realm results to an array as it defeats the lazy loading aspect of Realm and additionally can overload memory if there are too many objects. Additionally it also breaks the live updating aspect of Realm objects. There's not iteration code but you also don't have a results object to iterate over as its an array. `partitionValue` may be incorrect as well. Can you verify that matches whats in the console?